# Can someone explain why this happens? (Dividing variables with exponents)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, fractions

Alright, so let's say I have $$\frac{x^{-6}}{-x^{-4}}$$ The answer is $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$, but why isn't it $\dfrac{1}{-x^2}$?

Comment: Why *would* it be $1/-x^2$?

Comment: For $n$ and $m$ integers, and $z\ne 0$, we have $$\frac{z^n}{z^m}=z^{n-m}$$

Comment: Now that the denominator changed to $-x^{-4}$, it does come out $1/(-x^2)=-1/x^2=-x^{-2}$

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about what negative exponents really mean. Consider the following list
$$2^3 = 8$$
$$2^2 = 4$$
$$2^1 = 2$$
Notice that every time we decrease an exponent, we divide by 2. Continuing this list, we have that
$$2^3 = 8$$
$$2^2 = 4$$
$$2^1 = 2$$
$$2^0 = 1$$
$$2^{-1} = 1/2$$
$$2^{-2} = 1/4$$
Rather interesting, we see a pattern: $2^{-n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$. Therefore there is no reason for a negative sign on the quantity itself, since we're successively dividing by **positive** numbers.

Comment: I think you missed the negative signs in some of your exponents in the list. :)

Comment: I want to know why the x in the denominator isn't negative.

Comment: That negative sign in the original problem was not there. In the case that that is the actual problem, then yes you would need a negative.

Answer (score 2):

It might help you see what's going on if you write them as two story fractions: $$\frac{x^{-6}}{-x^{-4}}=\frac{\left(\dfrac{1}{x^6}\right)}{\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^4}\right)}=\underbrace{\color{red}{\frac{1}{x^6}\times -\frac{x^4}{1}}}_{\large \color{blue}{\text{by the reciprocal rule}}}=-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{-x^2}$$ So you are correct, and the "answer" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If the questions is asking; simplify $\frac {x^{-6}}{-x^{-4}}$, then the answer is $\frac {1}{-x^2}$. But if the answer is $\frac {1}{x^2}$, then I believe the question is $\frac {x^{-6}}{(-x)^{-4}}$.